# Streaming low-latency video from a low-spec Linux box?

Tags: linux, video, audio, streaming, webcam

For a robotics project, I have a really low-spec Linux box (76MB ram, 729MHz processor, relatively good video card...yes, we're talking about a [Nintendo Wii](http://en.Wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii#Technical_specifications) here) which I want to use to stream video from a webcam over the network. I will be connecting one client to it on LAN (with the slowest link being 100MBit ethernet). I need to have as little latency as possible for this because the video will be my only remote control feedback mechanism.

The computer which I will be viewing the stream on is a crappy laptop with an "integrated graphics" card, so I need something relatively lightweight.

The webcam can film in up to 1280x1024, bonus points for transmitting at that resolution.

I need some command line software which can read from the webcam and stream the video in a lightweight manner which can preferably be read by mplayer. Bonus points for toggleable audio or HD screenshots on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [VideoLAN](http://www.videolan.org/), especially the "VideoLAN streaming solution" chapter in the [FAQ](http://www.videolan.org/support/faq.html)

Comment: Good, except that it gives "Invalid Instruction" when run on the wii, and building from source is not possible due to missing dependencies in Lenny's package management system.